# Azure KeyVault Client Certificate and Service Principal renewal

Tags: azure, client-certificates, azure-keyvault

My Azure solution is compound of various modules and each one is identified by a service principal in the Azure AD, using a certificate. I would like to have the benefits of the KeyVault Certificates auto renewal in order to renew the client certificates. I know that the Web Apps certificate bindings are automatically updated when the certificate is renewed, but what about the service principal ones ?

Does Azure KeyVault auto-renewal also automatically take care of the certificate of the service principal in the Azure AD ?

Comment: what is a `certificate of a service principal`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 a service principal in the Azure AD can be created using 2 types of credentials: ClientId + ClientSecret or ClientId + Certificate

Comment: ah, i understood what you mean, i doubt that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While certificate in the KeyVault itself will be auto-renewed if it is either self-signed or any of the supported [Public CA's](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/) based on policy you set (could be n days before expiry or at some % of its lifetime) it may not automatically update the service principal. You should be able to achieve that by slightly tweaking this [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#create-service-principal-with-certificate-from-certificate-authority) to get the cert from KeyVault and also automating this through Azure Automation or any other way.